# HP smart array p212 raid controller. Only two arrays possible? because of missing RAM on raid card?

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

I bought a HP Proliant gen8 microserver. In it I installed 1 * 500GB SSD connected to SATA port 5 as a bootable disk and 4 * 3TB HDD connected to a HP smart array p212.

What I would like to do is create 1 array using HDD 1 and 2 as a RAID 1 configuration. The other hard drives will contain data that does not need mirroring and may be in a RAID 0 configuration, one array for HDD 3 and one array for HDD 4. This would become array A (RAID HDD 1 and 2), array b (RAID 0, HDD 3) and array c (RAID 0, HDD 4). I was able to do this on the soft RAID functionality. But using that also introduced other issues.

My issue is that I do not get the posibility for creating array c. It will let me create array a and array b. And it will show me that HDD 4 is a unassigned disk. In the image below you can see that the 'create array' button is gone.

[Current array config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDOL8.jpg)

I am able to create array A and array B both in RAID 1 and use all 4 HDD's. So connecting to all drives is not an issue.

Could the fact that I am not using any cache memory on the p212 card be the issue? From what I understand this would mainly upgrade your throughput of read and write data.

If I do need this RAM module, do I realy need a backup battery to get it operational like the seller for the card is telling me? From what I understand the battery is only needed in case of a power outage and it is not mandatory. 
From a risk perspective I am willing to take the risk of power outage because I would not mind if some data gets scrambled since this system would be a backup for photo's on mobile devices. The other data on the RAID 0 disks are more of a 'nice to have' nature, so data loss on those disks wouldn't matter anyway.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (It's been a while but) select unassigned drives, select the drive and then select "create array."

Comment: BBWC has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @MarkWagner I already tried to do that.  when I select the drive, I only get the options 'View details' and 'Identify device'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only 2 arrays (logical volumes as per HPE) are supported without cache memory. 
Check controller specifications:
https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/getdocument.aspx?docname=c04111625

> Logical Volumes Supported
>
> Zero Memory, Up to 2 logical volumes
>
> 256mb cache, Up to 64 logical volumes

Comment: I did look at this document but I was not able to find this information. Would I also need the backup battery as well? I was hoping to avoid it.

Comment: Page 19. If you don't care about data safety, you can configure RAID0 with HDD3 and HDD4 and then create two volumes in OS.

Comment: Alright, found it. thanks a lot. I will buy a cache module and test it. what kind would you prefer? BBWC or FBWC?

Comment: I don't think that cache type will play any role in your case. Check the article to understand the difference: https://community.hpe.com/t5/BladeSystem-Server-Blades/Flash-Based-Write-Cache-FBWC-amp-Battery-Backed-Write-Cache-BBWC/td-p/1517#.XIEp8Cj7RPY

Comment: Roger that, I just ordered a 512 MB FBWC module. It was a bit more priced but I think it will worth it. Thank you again. I'll mark your answer when I installed en tested it. I expect it to arrive the day after tomorrow. I can't wait to finally start working on my server.